# Angular: How go to have multiple PWA app under same domain

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I am facing a big problem since last one week.

I am working with Angular app which have one feature like create Business Card with url dedicated. Example is given below.

**mysite.com (main site)**

**mysite.com/card1 (card1)**

**mysite.com/card2 (card2)**

So how to have pwa for each of this card seperately.

1. I don't think this would require code i did
2. I know this can be achieved by having multiple service workers.

Above 2 points i know. Please help me with this. I had searched a lot about this but I didn't find anything specific for **Angular**.

Comment: angular is a great framework for building SPA and even more - complex SPA is a main use case for Angular. you will have one app with several pages on different urls. is it acceptable for you?

Comment: I have a requirement of having different app and it should be installed as standalone application for different cards. Thanks for replying. @Andrei

Comment: May I ask why a requirement for a different app?  Could each be a separate Angular module loaded only when called?